PDFKit - PDFPage.characterBounds(at:) returns wrong character bounds
Apple's PDFKit function PDFPage.characterBounds(at:) returns wrong character bounds in iOS 18, 18.1 and 18.2 betas. It breaks apps that read character positions from PDF files through PDFKit.
Has anybody found a workaround for this issue?
Note: I have filed feedback to Apple during the current beta cycle (FB14843671), so far not resulting in a bug fix. iOS 17 betas had the same issue, but got fixed near the end of the beta cycle.
